# OAuth2 using grant_type "password" and "code" sharing one session (implicit flow, code flow)

Tags: session, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, session-cookies

I need your help regarding best practices and OAuth2/SSO.

At the moment I have 4 Websites:

1. The SSO Server (sso.abc.com)
2. The company site (www.abc.com) using the **implicit flow**.
3. The administration site (admin.abc.com) using the **code flow**.
4. The subdomain (webshop.abc.com) using the **code flow**.

Let's say I navigate to *admin.abc.com*. 
The client will request an authorization code and I will be able to sign-in with my user credentials on the login-form provided by *sso.abc.com*.

After the authorization I will end with a session on *admin.abc.com* and another session on *sso.abc.com*.

Since *webshop.abc.com* is using the same SSO Server, I will be able to share the session between this page and the administration site (because of the SSO session).

The main page however wants to use/keep their own login-form.
So their idea is, to use the implicit flow to authenticate on the token endpoint directly.

Now my question:

How can I share the (sso-) session with *www.abc.com*, since it exchanges the user credentials directly via the /token endpoint?

(I don't want to login a second time.)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I will try to create a session cookie on the sso server when the /Token endpoint is called directly. Like this I can switch from **www.abc.com** to the other pages.

Next step is, to add an /Authorize call from the main page to the sso, to check if there is a session.

If so, I take the AuthCode and go the code flow way.

If not, I ignore the redirect and show the login-form from the main page and go the implicit flow.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "The main page however wants to authenticate with their own login-form, using the implicit flow to authenticate the user credentials and get a token directly." in more detail? Because it sounds like a contradiction with your question about sharing the SSO session.

Comment: I changed it ! Thx

Comment: So the www.abc.com has a form, where it gets user's credentials and sends them to the /token endpoint without going to the OAuth2 auth endpoint? And do you want to keep the credentials form there or replace it with the standard OAuth2 authentication process?

Comment: Exactly. Well they want to keep their form. 
They dont want any redirect or SSO form on their website.